# Angular2 CORS access-Control-allow-headers

Tags: asp.net, angular, cors, iis-10

Edit: Realized my mistake. "Access-Control-Allow-Request-Headers" should be "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"

I am trying to use a get api with a header, but I keep getting Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I am using angular2 and calling a webapi using asp.net on an iis10 server

I edited my IIS10 already, and I edited the web.config... What else can I do?
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error message talks about a header named `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` while you set the `Access-Control-Allow-Request-Headers` in the config file.

I'd also suggest considering moving the CORS configuration [in the Web API config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors) as it's a matter related to your application.

Answer (score 0):

*sigh.. "Access-Control-Allow-Request-Headers" should really be

"Access-Control-Allow-Headers"